# Pass parameters in batch file from powershell

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have made a batch file in Windows. The content in that file is like this

**test.bat**

```
echo %1
```

Now when I send an argument from command line like this

```
test.bat "hello"
```

then it outputs always `%1`. It should be `hello`.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are using power-shell. you need to use the following in your bat file:

```
echo $1
```

Here is Converting DOS Batch Files to Shell Scripts

```
 http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dosbatch.html
```

Answer (score 2):

This is really odd - something in your assumptions about what is in the file is not correct. Here is the output from my pc doing exactly what you describe:

```
C:\windows\system32>copy con test.bat
echo %1
^Z
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\windows\system32>test.bat hello

C:\windows\system32>echo hello
hello
```

I suspect the file has something different in than what you describe

Comment: I am doing right but I can get it that why code is not working perfect on my PC.

Comment: Is that all test.bat contains?

Comment: please post more detail: an actual dump of the file and actual output from a run like the one above

Comment: @user230910 good catch. Actually I was testing that file using git but when I try this using cmd it works fine